# why i am getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, javabeans

i found a java file on the web that allows me to read a pdf in a url and save it to my local machine, 
i have sucsesfully compiled it and customized as a javabean so i can useit in my app, but when i test it i am getting the next error message.
i have added the library (PDFOne.jar file) to my project in netbean and averything compiles well.

in fact, the program detect my pdf url and validate it saying is a valid pdf file, but then the error comes:

any tip ? i am completely new in java world.
thanks in advance

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gnostice/pdfone/PdfDocument
    at Read_PDF_From_URL.setProperty(Read_PDF_From_URL.java:51)
    at oracle.forms.handler.ComponentItem.setCustomProperty(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.handler.ComponentItem.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.handler.JavaContainer.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.handler.UICommon.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onUpdateHandler(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processSet(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessageReal(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processEventEnd(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gnostice.pdfone.PdfDocument
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
```

**here is part of the source code:**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import oracle.forms.properties.*;
import oracle.forms.ui.*;

import com.gnostice.pdfone.PdfDocument;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class Read_PDF_From_URL   extends VTextArea {
    private static final ID GEN = ID.registerProperty("sav");

  public boolean setProperty(ID id, Object value) {
    boolean retorno = true;

    try {
       if (id == GEN) {
           System.out.println("if");         
         URL url1 =
      new URL("http://www.gnostice.com/downloads/Gnostice_PathQuest.pdf");

      byte[] ba1 = new byte[1024];
      int baLength;
      FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("sibdownload.pdf");

      // Contacting the URL
      System.out.print("Connecting to " + url1.toString() + " ... ");
      URLConnection urlConn = url1.openConnection();

      // Checking whether the URL contains a PDF
      if (!urlConn.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {
          System.out.println("FAILED.\n[Sorry. This is not a PDF.]");
      } else {
        try {

          // Read the PDF from the URL and save to a local file
          InputStream is1 = url1.openStream();
          while ((baLength = is1.read(ba1)) != -1) {
              fos1.write(ba1, 0, baLength);
          }
          fos1.flush();
          fos1.close();
          is1.close();

          // Load the PDF document and display its page count
          System.out.print("DONE.\nProcessing the PDF ... ");
          PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
          try {
            doc.load("sibdownload.pdf");
            System.out.println("DONE.\nNumber of pages in the PDF is " +
```

Comment: Was there originally a `package` statement in this Java source?

Comment: Thanks for comments. i have found the problem. i needed to include the PDFOne.jar in my classpath. But know i am getting a new error : [access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "sibdownload.pdf" "read")]
any work arroud on this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my question... The first thing was that I've needed to include the jar file in my classpath and the second thing that I've needed to sign the jar file.